# Google App script sheets - How to get the highlighted range and write data to it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to write data that is generated from my own function to the highlighted cell of the user. It should be able to take single cell and multiple cell highlights.

```
   if(isNaN(text))
     ui.alert('Input is not a number');
   else{

     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var activeRangeList = sheet.getActiveRangeList();

     if(activeRangeList==null)
       ui.alert('No range selected');
     else{
       var rgMyRange = sheet.getRange("B1:B10");
       rgMyRange.setValue(myFunc(NumberOfRowsHighlighted,parseInt(text)))
     }
   }
```

I would like for the user to highlight a range, when the scripts run i would need to get the number of rows highligted along with the input number to be passed to myfunc. The function always generates an array the same size as the number of highlighted rows. Finally i would like to be able to write back to the highlighted cell using the array return by the ffunction.

sample return of myfunct

```
[1,2,3,...,100]
```

I am having a hard time reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection) since google doesnt really define what is a Range or a RangeList and an example of the data returned. So if anybody can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of this `GENERATEGROUP(10,parseInt(text))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it, using different objects and functions, it is somewhat similar to the first one

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();

  if(selection.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()==null)
    ui.alert('No range selected');

  else{

    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(selection.getActiveRange().getA1Notation());
    range.setValues(GENERATEGROUP(10,parseInt(text)));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the function `GENERATEGROUP(10,parseInt(text))` outputs but here's a solution that writes to Row and Column numbers each cell in the active range (i.e. the users selection)

```
//es6-V8
function writeActiveRange() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  let v=rg.getValues();
  const row=rg.getRow();
  const col=rg.getColumn();
  v.forEach(function(r,i){r.forEach(function(c,j){v[i][j]=`Row:${row+i},Col:${col+j}`;});});
  rg.setValues(v);
}
```